# Does Npgsql support Rdlc reports?

Tags: npgsql

Why doen't the Npgsql connection string in .net project doesn't show up while trying to add a dataset for a rdlc report ?The same Npgsql connection string does work for all the other functions of the project except for the rdlc section.Can any1 suggest if Npgsql supports rdlc or not ?If not how to add rdlc reports to a dot net project with postgresql as backend.Thanks

Comment: You may want to explain what exactly you're referring to - what exactly is rdlc and what is its connection to Npgsql.

Comment: rdlc(Report Definition Language Client-side) is a kind of reporting wizard to display dynamic or static data to the end user.I mostly work with .net and sql server and didn't face any problem connecting the report wizard to sql server database.Currently I am trying to migrate a sql server database to postgresql.I have successfully migrated the database to postgres however I am stuck with the reports as stated earlier the npgsql connection string in web.config file of the .net project is not identified by the report wizard..A help or guide in this regard will be very useful @ShayRojansky